# div object as variable can´t be passed to a function(plain Java Script)

Tags: javascript, html

I declared a variable box and want to change it´s style property. Somehow it´s not working and I get an error like this "can not set property'style' of null object. I don´t understand why this isn´t working. But when I put the variable inside the function it works.Does anyone else had the same problem and how do you fixed it?

I just notice it works inside Stack Overflow. But not in Google Chrome and IE.

```js
var boxPosition = 50;
var boxSpeed = 5;
var limit = 300;
var box = document.getElementById('box');


function draw(){
  box.style.left = boxPosition + 'px';
}
```

```css
#box{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "Style.css">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Motion.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "box" onclick="draw();"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The script comes before the elements are available in the DOM. You have to move the script to right before `</body>`